# ¿Cómo aplicar cambios sobre registros mySQL desde un DataGrid con C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un programa de administración de inventarios, con mySQL y Visual Studio (Proyecto de tipo WPF), tengo un DataGrid donde se visualizan busquedas hechas por el usuario, dando click a un botón "Editar" puedes modificar los datos de la tabla y (aquí es dónde esta mi problema) seguido de eso se puede hacer click en un botón de "Guardar cambios" para modificar esos registros pero, siempre salta este error. ¿Qué puedo hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

Nota: No se creo una función que conecta a la base de datos ya que se agrego la conexión mediante un ADO.NET Entity Data Model, por lo cual creo que queda descartado usar un MySqlCommand.

> Se produjo la excepción System.InvalidCastException.
>   HResult=0x80004002   Mensaje = No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   'MS.Internal.NamedObject' al tipo 'Pvm1.articulos'. 
>   Origen =

```
private void Btn_salvar_cambios(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                pvmEntidades BaseDeDatos = new pvmEntidades(); //Está es mi base de datos
                articulos articulos = new articulos(); //Esto representa la tabla de la base de datos

                foreach (articulos row in DataGV.Items)//En esta linea marca el error, DataGV es el nombre de mi DataGrid.
                {
                    //articulos = (articulos) row;
                    articulos = row;
                    BaseDeDatos.SaveChanges();

                }


            }
```

Comment: si tu clase base se llama articulos, y tu variable tambien, el lio que se debe estar haciendo el compilador en la linea articulos = row debe ser monumental.. cambia uno de los nombres y volve a probar...

Comment: No funcionó, sigue dando este error: System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' al tipo 'Pvm1.articulos'.'

Comment: Los items que cargas en la DG son del tipo articulos?

Comment: Si, son del tipo articulos

Answer (score 0):

### Solucionado

Bastó con cambiar el "foreach" por un "for" que pasara por todos los datos de mi DataGrid sin contar el último ya que este por algún motivo estaba vacío y eso hacía que saltara el error, ahora el problema es que el registro se duplica pero ya estoy en eso. Así quedó el código.

```
private void Btn_salvar_cambios(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pvmEntidades BaseDeDatos = new pvmEntidades();
            articulos articulo = new articulos();
            articulos articulo_DB = new articulos();

            for (int i = 0; i < DataGV.Items.Count -1; i++)
            {

                articulo = (articulos)DataGV.Items[i];
                articulo_DB = BaseDeDatos.articulos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id_articulos.Equals(articulo.id_articulos));

                articulo_DB.cantidad = articulo.cantidad;
                articulo_DB.nombre = articulo.nombre;
                articulo_DB.descripcion = articulo.descripcion;
                articulo_DB.tamaño = articulo.tamaño;
                articulo_DB.color = articulo.color;
                articulo_DB.tipo = articulo.tipo;
                articulo_DB.cantidad = articulo.cantidad;
                articulo_DB.código = articulo.código;
                articulo_DB.marca = articulo.marca;
                articulo_DB.ubicacion = articulo.ubicacion;


                //BaseDeDatos.articulos.Add(articulo_DB);
                BaseDeDatos.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```